# Suffices to check a morphism of schemes is unramified on closed points.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, etale-cohomology

I am starting to read Milne's Etale Cohomology notes and in it they mention:

> A morphism $\varphi :Y \rightarrow X$ is unramified if it is of finite type and if the maps $\mathcal{O}_{X,f(y)} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ are unramified for all $y\in Y$. It suffices to check the condition for the closed points $y$ of $Y$.

I wasn't really sure how it suffices to check that the condition holds for closed points. This is a local definition so we can check it locally: consider a homomorphism of rings $\varphi :R\rightarrow S$. Then if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal in $S$ which is contained in the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ then we can't really compare the fields $S_{\mathfrak{p}}/{\frak{p}}$ and $S_{\frak{m}}/{\frak{m}}$. I don't think there's a canonical morphism in either direction.

I've also searched around and I couldn't find a mention of this anywhere. Is this statement true? and if so why?

Comment: Are you sure there's not some assumption missing? There are schemes with [no closed points](https://www.math.utah.edu/~schwede/Papers/SchemeWithoutPoints.pdf), for instance.

Comment: @KReiser I think actually Milne assumes every scheme is locally Noetherian, but I can't really see how that helps.

Comment: @KReiser Do you mind checking the answer that I posted? I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

No one answered my question yet and I did some digging. Not quite sure if this is absolutely correct or not, but again if $\varphi: Y \rightarrow X$ is unramified at $y\in Y$ then this means we can find affine opens around $y \in U = \text{Spec}(A)$ and $\varphi(y) \in V = \text{Spec}(R)$ such that $\Omega_{A/R} = 0.$ Now $\Omega_{A/R}$ is just an $A-$module  so we can check that it vanishes by checking it at the maximal ideals, and vanishing at the maximal ideals is then equivalent to checking that the map is unramified at the closed points.

Comment: This is all fine until you declare that the maximal ideals of $A$ correspond to closed points of $Y$. It's certainly true that every closed point of $Y$ will be a closed point of $\operatorname{Spec} A$, but this implication is not reversible without additional hypotheses. For instance, if $R$ is a DVR with fraction field $K$, then the point $(0)\in\operatorname{Spec} R$ is closed in the affine open subscheme $\operatorname{Spec} K\subset \operatorname{Spec} R$ but not as a point of $\operatorname{Spec} R$.